# Vee Validate Nuxt JS Property or method "required" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: forms, vue.js, validation, nuxt.js, vee-validate

I'm new to Vue and Nuxt and I can't seem to overcome this error:

> [Vue warn]:Property or method "required" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

this is the source code:

vee-validate.js :

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import {ValidationProvider, ValidationObserver,extend} from 'vee-validate'
import {required,email} from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'
Vue.component('ValidationProvider',ValidationProvider)
Vue.component('ValidationObserver',ValidationObserver)

extend('required' ,{
    ...required,
    message:'This field is required'
})


extend('email',{
    ...email,
     message:'This field is required'

})
```

and for the form :

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="col-6 pr-2">
      <label for="name">*Name </label> <br />
      <ValidationObserver>
        <ValidationProvider v-slot="{ errors }" mode="passive" rules="required">
          <input id="name" v-model="required" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name" />
          <span class="validation-span">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
        </ValidationProvider>
      </ValidationObserver>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 pr-2">
      <label for="company">Company</label> <br />
      <input id="company" type="text" label="Company" placeholder="Name of your company" />
      <br />
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 pr-2">
      <br />
      <ValidationObserver>
        <ValidationProvider v-slot="{ errors }" mode="passive" rules="required|email">
          <label for="email">*Email</label> <br />
          <input id="email" v-model="email" type="email" placeholder="example@email.com" /> <br />
          <span class="validation-span">{{ errors[0] }}</span>
        </ValidationProvider>
      </ValidationObserver>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi, I could't get it to work at the moment. I will rewrite everything from scratch and reinstall vee-validate adding the knowledge you were kind enough to share and see where that takes me. Thank you very much for your reply !

Comment: Hi, did you achieved this one? :)

Comment: Not yet, no. But I haven't had the time to work on it properly. I'll get it done this week and let you know how it went. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how we do it in my team.

`/utils/vee-validate-rules.js`

```js
import { extend } from 'vee-validate'
import { email as defaultEmail, required as defaultRequired } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'

const email = extend('email', {
  ...defaultEmail,
})

const required = extend('required', {
  ...defaultRequired,
})


export { extend, email, required }
```

Some `.vue` file

```html
<script>
import { extend, required, email } from '~/utils/vee-validate-rules'

export default {
  beforeCreate() {
    extend('required', { ...required, message: this.$t('veeValidate.required') })
    extend('email', { ...email, message: this.$t('veeValidate.email') })
  },
}
</script>
```

This works great so far. Could be done better in terms of i18n tho.

Also, don't forget to transpile it too

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
build: {
  transpile: ['vee-validate/dist/rules']
}
```